# I dont understand one simple line of code

Tags: java, arrays, boolean-expression

Below is line:

```
if (!seatNum[i])
```

I don't understand the purpose of this line.Code:

```
 if(economyClass<5) {
    for(int i=5;i<seatNum.length;i++) {
        if(!seatNum[i]) {
            seatNum[i]=true;
            System.out.println("Economy Class. Seat number: "+(i+1));
            economyClass++;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `!` negates whatever logical expression follows

Comment: if ( !seatNum[i]) is the same as: if ( seatNum[i] == false )

Comment: i know it negates but do not undertand what it checkes.

Comment: it checks that the variable stored in seatNum[i] is false

Comment: ```seatNum``` is variable, ```[i]``` is indexing, ```!``` is negation. So, this line of code negate value on index ```i``` of variable ```seatNum```

Comment: `setNum` is an array with component type `boolean`: `boolean[]`. So `seatNum[i]` returns the `boolean` value at index `i`. This then is negated by the operator `!` and evaluated as the if-condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `seatNum` is array of boolean, which mark if seat is taken.

`if(!seatNum[i])` is if seat not taken, similar but shorter way of checking `seatNum[i] == false`

You are marking it as taken `seatNum[i]=true;` and increase the economyClass number by `economyClass++;`

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that `seatNum[]` is an array of booleans , that means:
if the element at index `i` of `seatNum`  is false, then proceed.

you can also read that as : `if(seatNum[i] == false)`

Answer (score 1):

`seatNum[]` must be a boolean array and `!seatNum[i]` expands to `(seatNum[i]==false)` which evaluates to `true` or `false`. So it is checking if seatNumber is not occupied and if not occupied alloting it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the ! is also called Boolean negation operator and what it does is inverting a boolean value:

```
!true => false
!false => true
```

In order for the posted code to compile the seatNum array should contain booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I can assume seatNum array as of boolean type as you have not mentioned the data type of array seatNum.
And if I am correct in my assumption, the content of array in the ith index can be true or false, if !true which is equals to false, the immediate line of the code sets true in the ith index. 
In one line, ! is a logical not operator and not of true means false.

Hope this helps you to explore more about operators in java